# Linux Mint Menu is Overflowing

Tags: linux-mint

My Linux Mint Cinnamon’s menu is growing bigger than the usual. How to edit it because I couldn’t find any menu editor apps.

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Your image shows the "all applications" grouping selected - this will flatten the structure and list all of the applications, so it's going to get long.  If you highlight one of the groups, e.g. office, it will give you a shorter list.

Comment: I don't use Cinnamon, but did you try right-clicking on the menu icon?  There is often a menu edit option there.

Comment: @GregHNZ It doesn't work either. Even though one of the groups only have two applications, the height of the menu still doesn't shorten.

Comment: @fixer1234 There's is a configure options, but the options is for the menu applet not for configure the menu content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the menu icon

Select "Configure"

Hit "Open the menu editor" which is a button that goes all the way across the dialog.

[image: Config]

[image: Editor]

Comment: It's worked, thanks. I didn't see than "Open the menu editor" button existed.